# How does unique_together work in Django-nonrel?

Tags: django, mongodb, django-nonrel, django-mongodb-engine

I am using django-nonrel and django-mongodb engine.

In engine's [documentation](https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/model-options.html), it says that it supports django's Meta options.

I tried using `unique_together` in a model as such:

```
class Bottler(models.Model):

    location = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    source = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    transactionID = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("location","source"),)
```

However this doesn't seem to have worked since I could create duplicates without any error being raised.

I know `unique_together` is enforced at the database level.

What does that translate to in MongoDB? 
Do I have to validate it manually?

Comment: have you tried them as a list as opposed to a tuple: `unique_together = ("location","source",)`? Django supports both but maybe it's a bug with django-nonrel/mongodb

Comment: Tried it both ways... didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `syncdb` in order to sync database indices.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow syncbd will not update your indexes in mongodb. What you can try (if possible in your situation) is to delete the collection and then run syncdb. In my case it did create the indexes then.